# Post on facebook wall from server instead of client app

Tags: iphone, facebook, grails, httpwebrequest, facebook-wall

I have been working on an iphone app (with client-server communication) that connects to facebook via fConnect. The facebook authentication and other communication is being handled at iphone app and they all are working fine.

Now, due to some optimization issues we want to handle the fb wall post functionality of app from server side instead of client side. To achieve the task what we are doing is send all the data(includes fb access token as well) to server side and send a http post request to facebook via graph api. In the response it send us an error:

> {"error":{"message":"Invalid token: \"610446057\".  An ID has already
>   been specified.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}

The sample code of http request is pasted below:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getParams().setParameter("http.useragent", "Test Client");

PostMethod method = new PostMethod("https://graph.facebook.com/610446057?access_token=MY_VALID_TOKEN_HERE");
method.addParameter("id", "610446057");
method.addParameter("name", "Zunair Minhas");
method.addParameter("picture", "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/276791_19292868552_1958181823_s.jpg");
method.addParameter("link", "http://www.google.com.pk");
method.addParameter("company_overview", "FB Wall post without fb integration. It is a simple Http Post request.");
client.executeMethod(method);

def reader = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
String data = reader.readLines().join()
method.releaseConnection();
```

The server is written is Grails 2.0.1.

I have followed the fb post sample provided here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Can you please guide what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Zunair Minhas

Comment: Don't write your access token in a SO question! If it is valid anyone can use it!

Comment: Why you are using the token in the URL instead of: method.addParameter("access_token", "MY_VALID_TOKEN");

 ?

Comment: I have also tried it with this approach but it didn't go well. I have received the same response as received earlier.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is remove the line:

```
method.addParameter("id", "610446057");
```

You are passing that via the graph url `https://graph.facebook.com/610446057`

---

To post to a wall just do

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=<xxx>
```

Where the access token is the token the user gave you to write on the wall.  When you do that it will resolve who you are sending the message to and post all the wall as the app that was authorized.

Comment: I did not see your answer, Stack Overflow refreshing bugs strike once again :-)

Comment: I did this because it was mentioned in the example here [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). But when I do remove this line I get this response: 
'{"error":{"message":"(#100) Can only call this method on valid test users for your app","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}'

Any more suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately, this url didn't work as well. Same response received. 

:(

I have also tried to post the request on user's wall via Graph API explorer and same result appeared there too. Can you please verify if i am not missing any step or any special configuration setting?

Comment: Can you post the URL you used? And make sure you are using the token the user granted you, not the token for the app.

Comment: Does this works when the server and the user are not in the same location ? (I have seen that once a user changes location/country, facebook website proceed to identity verification)

Answer (score 0):

You are specifing an ID which you already have in the URL

try to remove

```
method.addParameter("id", "610446057");
```